# What is "ts" in "tsclient" when accessing local resource in RDP?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

Could anyone tell me what the abbrevation `ts` stands for in `tsclient` when using this special name for accessing local disk during a Remote Desktop connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stands for "Terminal Services Client".

More information here, for example: *[Remote Desktop Connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection)*

(It is also related to Terminal Server client, its Linux corresponding program - see *[tsclient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsclient)*.)